# Mongo query a log collection with C# Api

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

To contextualize:

A Batch file has BachItems
Each BatchItem is a row and has a line number.
Each row is processed in order.

I'm new to NoSQL and mongo and I'd like to know how to query the last processing step executed (most recent EventType column) for each BatchItem (line number), filtering by BatchId?
For example, it should return the following result for BatchId "102030":

[image]

I believe I can achieve this using Aggregate and Group functions but don't know how.
Thanks.

Comment: have you looke this:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
db.batch.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
             "BatchId": 102030
        }
    }, 
    { $sort: { "Date": -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$BatchItemId",
            "doc": { "$push": { lastEventName: "$EventType" } },
        }
    },
    { 
        $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ["$doc", 0] }
    }}

])
```